# Read Long and String from a file using BufferedReader

Tags: java, string, buffer, long-integer

My Data is stored in a file in the following syntax:

```
12034567892410
asdf'gndzfm,ndsfgkmnds/fgmfgkjadf'jdakgjdafgj
.
.
.
```

Where the numbers are not actually written as strings, they are written as longs using writeLong.

I want to read these data from the file using BufferedReader.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

If you wrote them as binary data, you can't reliably read them using `BufferedReader`, which is meant for *text* data. It sounds like you probably want [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html). Basically, your reading code should match your writing code. If you post the code used to write the data, we should be able to put together the corresponding code to read it back again.